# React-Native Piker color

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I would like change the default color Picker (not item, the Picker view). I've try to add `style={{ color: "white" }}`, but no result.

```
<Picker
  selectedValue={this.state.language}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => this.setState({ language: itemValue })}
  style={{ color: "white" }}
>
  <Picker.Item label="EN" value="en-EN" />
  <Picker.Item label="FR" value="fr-FR" />
</Picker>
```

I've no warning and no error.
Any one have idea ?

Thank you community !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it:

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: "#f456" }}>
     <Picker selectedValue="a">
          <Picker.Item value="a" label="a" />
     </Picker>
</View>
```

Works fine in my case.[image]

Comment: Yes, `backgroundColor` work, but my background is black :) So i would like change the color to white :)